# .offset() bug with position absolute?

Tags: jquery, css

**The CSS:**

```
.flyoutdialog
{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    background-color: white;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

**The jQuery:** (dialog is 1 item of $(".flyoutdialog"), button is 1 item of $(".flyouticon") )

```
    var offset = button.offset();
    alert("top: " + offset.top + " left: " + offset.left);
    // dialog.offset({ top: offset.top - 5, left: offset.left + 25 });
    dialog.css("top", offset.top - 5 + "px");
    dialog.css("left", offset.left + 25 + "px");

    dialog.show("blind", { direction: "horizontal" }, 1000);

    var off2 = dialog.offset();
    alert("top: " + off2.top + " left: " + off2.left);
```

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="editor-label">
        <label for="Gebruikerscode">Gebruikerscode</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input id="gebruikerscode" name="gebruikerscode" type="text" value="" />
<a href="#" class="flyouticon">
    <img src="/img/help.png" alt="Flyout" width="16" /></a>

<div class="flyoutdialog grayicon" title="Gebruikerscode">
    <div class="title">
        <h4>
            Gebruikerscode</h4>
        <span class="closedialog ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
    <p>
        Dit is de code of 'gebruikersnaam' waarmee de school inlogt. Deze is uniek.</p>

</div>

</div>
```

**The Situation:**

I have an icon `.flyouticon` which, when hovered or clicked should open the `.flyoutdialog`
the dialog should come right next to it. to do that, i thought i'd use this code. This code WORKS, but only(!!!!) when i do not scroll down or to the right.

When NOT scrolled:

```
    var offset = button.offset();
    alert("top: " + offset.top + " left: " + offset.left); //top: 375 left: 288.29998779296875
    dialog.offset({ top: offset.top - 5, left: offset.left + 25 });
    dialog.show("blind", { direction: "horizontal" }, 1000);
    var off2 = dialog.offset();
    alert("top: " + off2.top + " left: " + off2.left); //top: 370 left: 313.29998779296875
```

working perfect. but, WHEN scrolled:

```
    var offset = button.offset();
    alert("top: " + offset.top + " left: " + offset.left); //top: 375 left: 288.29998779296875
    dialog.offset({ top: offset.top - 5, left: offset.left + 25 });
    dialog.show("blind", { direction: "horizontal" }, 1000);
    var off2 = dialog.offset();
    alert("top: " + off2.top + " left: " + off2.left); //**top: 142** left: 313.29998779296875
```

The TOP became smaller... why does this happen when I scroll??

**The Fix:**

```
    var offset = button.offset();
    alert("top: " + offset.top + " left: " + offset.left);
    //dialog.offset({ top: offset.top - 5, left: offset.left + 25 });

    dialog.css("top", offset.top - 5 + "px");
    dialog.css("left", offset.left + 25 + "px");

    dialog.show("blind", { direction: "horizontal" }, 1000);
    var off2 = dialog.offset();
    alert("top: " + off2.top + " left: " + off2.left);
```

**The Question:**

why did `offset()` not work correctly here? I'm using Firefox but I guess that doesn't matter. (Edit: in IE8 the same. so it's not the browser) Why do I have to use individual CSS properties when the dialog is positioned absolute anyway? and why does it go UP when I scroll down? why does 'TOP' become smaller?? when i just have set it with the value it should be. is this a bug in the setter of `offset()`?

**The Edit:**

well,

```
    dialog.offset({ top: offset.top + $(window).scrollTop() - 5, left: offset.left + 25 });
```

seems to work. But this doesn't answer my question **WHY?** Why does the offset automatically deduct the `scrollTop()` value from the `top` value in the setter? this doesn't make sense!

Comment: I have been having this problem, but the weird thing is that the *second* time you run the same function (with the same jQuery objects) it positions it as expected without adding scrollTop to it. I discovered that using .css instead of .offset worked perfectly, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

offset will not work as you expect when scrolling. you need to add  `$(window).scrollTop()` to it

Comment: so why does GETTING the offset work correctly even when scrolled, but SETTING it doesnt work, well, it acts strange...

Comment: from API: The .offset() setter method allows us to reposition an element. The element's position is specified relative to the document. If the element's position style property is currently static, it will be set to relative to allow for this repositioning... so check if the element becomes 'relative' when setting offset.

Comment: also. are you saying that if you do this: 
var myOffset = $('#elementId').offset();
$('#elementId').offset(myOffset);
and the window is scrolled, the element will move?

Comment: also try this. instead of setting the position with offset, set it with .css like so: .css({
   "top": top ,
   "left": left
  })

Comment: I DID do the css thing (see 'the fix') and that worked. I'll try the ofset = ofset thing, but i cant imagine that would make any difference to what i'm doing now.

Comment: so, the scrollTop worked, but it doesnt make sense. read my edit :)

Comment: Thank you! This answer stopped my brain from hurting!